# Inconsistent behaviour in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

This question may sound silly but lately I am facing certain inconsistent behaviour in case of shared PDF files in Google Drive. There are two PDF files - (1) One was shared about a year back and (2) the other shared recently. Both are shared with "Anyone can view" permission with permission to download and print (see the screen shots).

Now when I try to view the files without signing in to Google, I can view them both but when I try to download them, I can download the second one but NOT the first one without signing in.

I want the file to be downloadable by anyone without signing in to Google. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Madhurjya

[image: Sharing window]
[image: Downloading/Printing permission window]